# locate apache2ctl

Tags: apache, apache2, webserver

I can say apache2ctl graceful and my webserver restarts at an interactive shell. All is well. However, I need to say that in a shell script so I need the full path for apache2ctl. I have tried which and locate but nothing turns up which makes me very surprised. I looked in /usr/bin and there is no apache2ctl. How do I figure out where this lives?

I thought maybe it would be in /opt/local/apache2/bin but there is an apachectl in there...not a apache2ctl. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

@Jon Lin - Nice work...type apache2ctl told me `apache2ctl is aliased to`sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl'` . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It should be in /usr/sbin or /usr/local/sbin

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run `updatedb` before `locate` just in case

```
$ updatedb
# takes a while

$ locate apache2ctl
```

Or you can run `find / -name 'apache2ctl' 2> /dev/null` to search for your entire partition

Comment: im on a Mac and updated doesn't work. I tried the find command and it just hangs in my terminal.

Comment: Oh, you have finder on the top right of your screen right? Have you tried searching via that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `which`? (Not sure if that'd be present on a Mac, though it's pretty standard on most *nix systems; behaves rather like `where` on windows).